# what is the reason for this error "/usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: cannot execute binary file"

Tags: python-3.x, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i am trying to run a Linux command in python using bash in windows 10 which is executing a c program after bug fixing in the iteration.

i have already install gcc and other things.

```
subprocess.run(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe', 'sudo', 'timeout','10' ,'gcc', '-fprofile-arcs', '-ftest-coverage', '-o', './tcas', './tcas.c'])
```

i expect program should execute and give results.

Comment: Can you execute sudo manually? If you want to be helped, you should provide further information.

Comment: bash first argument should be a script, try `-c` to execute a command, in that case the command should be the next argument

Comment: yeah i can execute sudo manually.. if i execute it without sudo the error is /usr/bin/timeout: /usr/bin/timeout: cannot execute binary file

Comment: after putting -c as first argument the output is something like this:
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]

Comment: `bash.exe` is used to run shell scripts, not to execute binary files like `sudo` or `timeout`. Just remove the `bash.exe` argument (you might also need to supply the full path to `sudo`).

Comment: i am trying to run the linux command on windows, because the code i am using was written on linux environment, i am trying to run it on windows.

Comment: Gordon Davisson Sir, how to supply full path to sudo.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I found one solution.

There are many ways to run linux commands on windows.

I used cygwin. and sudo is not necessary for my code so i deleted it.

```
subprocess.run(['C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe', 'timeout','10' ,'gcc', '-fprofile-arcs', '-ftest-coverage', '-o', './tcas', './tcas.c'])
```

another way is to do it by installing linux virtual machine, but cygwin is more convenient.